# python: count number of duplicate entries in column

Tags: python, pandas, count

I have the following df:

```
date       id 
2000        1
2001        1 
2002        1
2000        2
2001        2
2002        2
2000        1
2001        1
2002        1
```

I want to count per date how many duplicates of id there are. The result should look like this because on every date the id 1 exists twice:

```
date       id        count
2000        1          2
2001        1          2
2002        1          2
2000        2          2
2001        2          2
2002        2          2
2000        1          2
2001        1          2
2002        1          2
```

I tried something like this, but this gives me 1s when id is 2.

```
df["count"] = df.groupby(["date", "id"])["count"].transform("count")
```

Comment: You should reword your question as it seems that you want ID 2 to count only once,  but your result example says otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can using `duplicated`

```
df.groupby('date').id.transform(lambda x : x.duplicated(keep=False).sum())
Out[208]: 
0    2
1    2
2    2
3    2
4    2
5    2
6    2
7    2
8    2
Name: id, dtype: int64
```

Comment: In pandas 1.3.5 it returns `AttributeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'id'`

Comment: @PD df.groupby('date')['id'].transform(lambda x : x.duplicated(keep=False).sum())

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your original code was a simple fix.

```
df['count'] = df.groupby(['date', 'id']).transform('count')
```

If I use group and transform it to a new column it will result in:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,3,size=(10, 3)), columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
df['count'] = df.groupby(['A', 'B'])['C'].transform('count')
print(df)
```

Resulting in:

```
   A  B  C  count
0  1  2  0      1
1  0  0  0      2
2  2  0  2      4
3  2  0  1      4
4  2  0  2      4
5  2  0  1      4
6  0  0  0      2
7  2  2  0      3
8  2  2  1      3
9  2  2  2      3
```

Answer (score 1):

Another simple solution: 
Try combining columns for date and ID into a third column "date"+"ID". Now you can use count to find the number of duplicates for each entry in the new 3rd column.

```
>>> dateID = [20001,20011,20021,20002,20012,20022,...]
>>> dateID.count("20001")
>>> 2
>>> dateID.count("20002")
>>> 2
```

You can count occurrences of each item in dateID using

```
[[x,dateID.count(x)] for x in set(dateID)]
```

Perhaps even easier, is to use counter:

```
>>> dateID=[x,y,z,x,y,z,z]
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> counter(dateID)
Counter({'x': 2, 'y': 2, 'z': 3})
```